# Postgres full text search on json

Tags: json, postgresql, pattern-matching, full-text-search, tsvector

I am dumping a json value into `text` field as I have some invalid json data that cannot be stored in `json`/`jsonb`. I would like to search and highlight `"Value16": 16711680` in the following example, but I am also getting a hit on `"Value20": 16711680`.

```
{
  "Value01": 122,
  "Value02": 25,
  "Value03": 9,
  "Value04": 538,
  "Value05": false,
  "Value06": 65534,
  "Value07": 2,
  "Value08": 0,
  "Value09": 2,
  "Value10": 1,
  "Value11": 0,
  "Value12": 0,
  "Value13": false,
  "Value14": 0,
  "Value15": 0,
  "Value16": 16711680,
  "Value17": 0,
  "Value18": 0,
  "Value19": 0,
  "Value20": 16711680,
  "Value21": 0,
  "Value22": 0
}
```

I tried following queries but did not work. Do I need to use any escape characters here?

`to_tsquery('Value16<->16711680')`

`to_tsquery('Value16&16711680')`

Basically I would like to hit only if key and value match *together*.
How to search for a key/value pair in the json text?

Comment: Please, *always* declare your version of Postgres. Often enough (like here) it is essential to the best solution.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter. Will do. I am using version 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your key and value are directly adjacent, I would suggest a **phrase search** (requires Postgres **9.6** or later):

```
...
WHERE my_tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'Value16 <-> 16711680');
```

Or:

```
...
WHERE my_tsvector @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple','Value16 16711680');
```

Only qualifies with the two search terms next to each other (ignoring noise characters in between). There is also the `<N>` variant of the operator for terms a couple of words apart.

Detailed explanation:

- [How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204588/how-to-search-hyphenated-words-in-postgresql-full-text-search/204601#204601)

You can even combine this with prefix matching:

- [Match a phrase ending in a prefix with full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155592/match-a-phrase-ending-in-a-prefix-with-full-text-search/41112803#41112803)