# Does the phrase search operator <-> work with JSONB documents or only relational tables?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb, string-search

Does the phrase search operator `<->` work with JSONB documents or only relational tables in PostgreSQL?

I haven't experimented with this yet, as I haven't yet set up Postgres hosting.  The answer to this question will help determine what database and what tools I will be using.

I found this sample code at: https://compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/:

```
SELECT document_id, document_text FROM documents  
WHERE document_tokens @@ to_tsquery('jump <-> quick');
```

I just need to know if this operator is supported by JSONB documents.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase search capability is integrated into the [text search ***data type*** `tsquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html). The [text search operator `@@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) you display takes a `tsvector` to the left and a `tsquery` to the right. And a `tsvector` can be built from any character type as well as from a JSON document.

Related:

- [Match a phrase ending in a prefix with full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155592/match-a-phrase-ending-in-a-prefix-with-full-text-search/41112803#41112803)

You can convert your `json` or `jsonb` document to a text search vector with one of the [dedicated functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
to_tsvector()
json(b)_to_tsvector()
```

Note that these only include *values* from the JSON document, not *keys*. Typically, that's what you want.
Basic example:

```
SELECT to_tsvector(jsonb '{"foo":"jump quickly"}')
    @@ to_tsquery('jump <-> quick:*');
```

Demonstrating ***prefix matching*** on top of phrase search while being at it. See:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

**Alternatively**, you can simply create the `tsvector` from the `text` representation of your JSON document to also include key names:

```
SELECT to_tsvector((jsonb '{"foo-fighter":"jump quickly"}')::text)
    @@ to_tsquery('foo <-> fight:*');
```

Produces a bigger `tsvector`, obviously.

Both can be indexed (which is the main point of text search). Only indexes are bound to relational tables. (And you can [index the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)!)
The expression itself can be applied to any value, not bound to tables like you seem to imply.