# Query JSONB column for any value where =?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column which has the unfortunate case of being very unpredictable, in some cases its value may be an array with nested values:

```
["UserMailer", "applicant_setup_3", ["5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9"]]
```

Sometimes it will be something with key/values like this:

```
[{"reference_id": "5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9", "job_dictionary": ["StatusUpdater", "FollowTwitterUsersJob"]}]
```

Is there a way to write a query which just treats the whole column like text and does a `like` to see if I can find the uuid in the big text blob? I want to find all the records where a particular uuid string is present in the jsonb column.

The query doesn't need to be fast or efficient.

Comment: Will it always be UUID strings that you are looking for? Also, as always, please declare your version of Postgres, the rough number of rows in the table, the avg size of the JSON column and whether performance matters.

Comment: Yes, it will always be a uuid type, no more than 100k rows in the table total. PG 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has search operator `?` for jsonb, but that would require you to search the json content recursively.

A possible, although not very efficient method, would to stringify the object and use `LIKE` to search it:

```
myjsonb::text LIKE '%"5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9"%'
myjsonb::text LIKE '%"' || myuuid || '"%'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qp9hymJw2HwVi4tLirnn9/0)**:

Comment: I want to kiss you on the forehead for this. You helped me after 18 hours of query building process.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the [jsonb operator `?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) is that it only considers top-level ***keys*** (including array elements), not ***values***, and no nested objects.

You seem to be looking for ***values*** and ***array elements*** (not keys) on any level. You can get that with a full text search on top of your `json`(`b`) column:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', jsonb_column)
    @@ tsquery '5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0184927f32db682a28c9a5667a290b7a)*

`to_tsvector()` extracts *values* and *array elements* on *all levels* - just what you need.

Requires Postgres 10 or later. `json(b)_to_tsvector()` in Postgres 11 offers more flexibility.

That's attractive for tables of non-trivial size as it can be supported with a full text **index** very efficiently:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_jsonb_column_fts_gin_idx ON tbl USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', jsonb_column));
```

I use the `'simple'` text search configuration in the example. You might want a language-specific one, like `'english'`. Doesn't matter much while you only look for UUID strings, but stemming for a particular language might make the index a bit smaller ...

Related:

- [LIKE query on elements of flat jsonb array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101530/like-query-on-elements-of-flat-jsonb-array/50111177#50111177)
- [Does the phrase search operator <-> work with JSONB documents or only relational tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763662/does-the-phrase-search-operator-work-with-jsonb-documents-or-only-relational/57763853#57763853)

While you are only looking for UUIDs, you might optimize further with a custom (`IMMUTABLE`) function to extract UUIDs from the JSON document as array (`uuid[]`) and build a functional GIN index on top of it. (Considerably smaller index, yet.) Then:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  my_uuid_extractor(jsonb_column) @> '{5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9}';
```

Such a function can be expensive, but does not matter much with a functional index that stores and operates on pre-computed values.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the array elements first by using `jsonb_array_elements(json)`, and then filter the casted string from those elements by like operator

```
select q.elm
  from
  (
    select jsonb_array_elements(js) as elm
      from tab
  ) q
 where elm::varchar like '%User%'

elm
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"UserMailer"
{"reference_id": "5cbffeb7-8d5e-4b52-a475-3cf320b2cee9", "job_dictionary": ["StatusUpdater", "FollowTwitterUsersJob"]}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=43688fda81164eea34ba71a7944700a6)</kbd>