# Using Postgres SIMILAR TO with Spring Data to match substring in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, pattern-matching

I have a record in a column with the value "very nice BMW 4 wheel drive i5".

How can I make a query that will find this if I provide a substring of this value? Let's say I want to find it by providing this "BMW i5"?

If I use the LIKE method then it expects the words in order.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')")
```

I'm using spring boot with Spring DATA. The database is postgres.

If I search the string on Postgres with this query I can find it, so the question how to do it with Spring DATA:

```
select name from product WHERE name similar TO '%((BMW) | (i5))%'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using Postgres SIMILAR TO ...

**Don't** use `SIMILAR TO`. It's utterly pointless. See:

- [Using SIMILAR TO for a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656452/using-similar-to-for-a-regex/24659766#24659766)
- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

Finding partial matches anywhere in the string is faster with the regular expression match operator **`~`** (or possibly the case insensitive variant `~*`). To match *two* strings in arbitrary order, use *two* expressions to keep it simple. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p WHERE p.name ~ 'BMW' AND p.name ~ 'i5';
```

But I suspect you want 'i5' *after* 'BMW' (with some or no noise in between):

```
SELECT * FROM Product p WHERE p.name ~ 'BMW.*i5';
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p WHERE p.name LIKE '%BMW%i5%';
```

Either can be supported with a trigram index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Product USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Requires the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) first. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

**Or** work with [**text search**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html). Then you can pass one string with multiple words (lexemes). Your query can look like:

```
... WHERE to_tsvecor(p.name) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'BMW i5');
```

Or use phrase search to find *'BMW' followed by 'i5'*:

```
... WHERE to_tsvecor(p.name) @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'BMW i5')
```

See:

- [How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204601/3684)

Text search is powerful, but you may have to familiarize yourself with it first. The manual provides all you need to know. The index could look like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Product USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', name));
```

Further reading:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10856/3684)
- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [Match a phrase starting with a prefix with full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155592/match-a-phrase-ending-in-a-prefix-with-full-text-search/41112803#41112803)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I translate  this to a query using Spring Data?

Comment: @AhmedAziz: Don't know much about Spring Data. But, eventually, it will be translated back to SQL form, that's what is sent to the DB.