# Npgsql Entity Framework Core PostgreSQL full text search by part of word

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I need to do full text search with searching by part of word using entity framework core.

I found this solution [Match a phrase ending in a prefix with full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155592/match-a-phrase-ending-in-a-prefix-with-full-text-search/34230829#34230829)

I try to write it with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`. I can parse input with `EF.Functions.PlainToTsQuery` but can't understand who to cast it to text.

Can I write it with ef core?

Comment: Have you tried following [the documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html?tabs=pg12%2Cv5)? Something like `.Where(p => p.SearchVector.Matches("Npgsql"))`?

Comment: @ShayRojansky I did not find solutions there, I need something like .Where( x => x.Search.Matches(NpgsqlTsQuery.Parse($@"to_tsquery('simple', regexp_replace(cast(plainto_tsquery('simple', 'Zend Fram') as text), E'(\'\\w+\')', E'\\1:*', 'g'))")) but it doesn't work

Comment: You can't embed an arbitrary PG SQL expression in a string and pass it to `NpgsqlTsQuery.Parse` - that isn't a valid ts_query. You can do something like: `.Where(x => x.Search.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("simple", "Zend Fram")))`, but there currently isn't a way to translate to regexp_replace (you can do the regex client-side if you want though, in .NET).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
.Where(p => p.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("Npgsql:*"))
```

It should work similarly to the raw query provided in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513501/postgresql-full-text-search-how-to-search-partial-words).

You can also use dollar sign interpolation with that to create some dynamic queries.